# Do Godot signals act as event handlers?

Tags: game-development, godot

I am a beginner at Godot game development. I am having some difficulties in understanding what a signal in Godot is. I have looked at the official documentation, but could not understand well. However, I am getting a feeling that these signals are some kind of event handler.

Please, help me to understand what a signal in godot is and whether my understanding of signals as event handlers is correct or not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct, a `signal` is an event that you can emit from a `Node`.

```
emit_signal("signalName") #emit's signal with no data
emit_signal("signalName", whateverDataToSend) #emit's signal with data
```

You can then register to receive notifications when the signal is fired, hence `connect` to a signal.

`nodeWithSignalInIt.connect( String signalName, Object target, String methodToCall)`

Note: `connect` needs to be called from a node that has the signal inside of it

It's also worth noting that signals can be found all over Nodes we use in Godot, for example, if you want to get notified of a collision entry on `Area2D` then just connect to that Area2D's `area_entered` signal.

[image]

Example:

```
func _ready() -> void:
        #NOTE: InteractiveArea is of type Area2D
        $InteractiveArea.connect("mouse_entered", self, "_on_mouse_entered")
        $InteractiveArea.connect("mouse_exited", self, "_on_mouse_exited")
        $InteractiveArea.connect("area_entered", self, "_on_player_entered")
        $InteractiveArea.connect("area_exited", self, "_on_player_exited")

func _on_mouse_entered() -> void:
    mouse_entered = true

func _on_mouse_exited() -> void:
    mouse_entered = false

func _on_player_entered(area: Area2D) -> void:
    print ("Player entered chest opening zone.")
    interaction_zone = true;

func _on_player_exited(area: Area2D) -> void:
    print ("Player exited chest opening zone.")
    interaction_zone = false
```

Comment: @Moon117 If my answer helped you understand `signals` better, please consider accepting it.